# Can one offer salah on behalf of someone else?

Tags: salat

Inspired from [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8472/18) question.

I know there is a difference of opinion on what kind of *salah* one can make up, but suppose one adopts the opinion that intentionally un-offered *salah* can be made up later. In this case, is it permissible to do it on behalf of another person? I.e. do the deed, and ask for the reward to be given to another person?

Answer (score 2):

You can pray if you want to, but it will not compensate for the missed prayers the other person has missed. i.e. your deeds will not be written in his books. To make a deed acceptable, there must be a "neyat"([intention](http://www.40hadithnawawi.com/index.php/the-hadiths/hadith-1)) for it. If the other person did not made the intention, how can he get its reward.
Also the books of deeds of a person is closed is closed except three things as mentioned in the hadith

The Messenger of Allah (PBUH) said:

> When a man dies, his deeds come to an end except for three things:
>   Sadaqah Jariyah (ceaseless charity); knowledge which is beneficial; or
>   a virtuous descendant who prays for him (the deceased).

[Sahih Muslim]